# Appearing a section of a website on another web page while continuously blinking

Tags: google-chrome, display

I was editing a post in Stackoverflow. I completed it and visited my profile page. When I moved the cursor down, (at 2/3 of the screen) I noticed that a section of the previous webpage is still appearing (while blinking) on my profile page.

*I took a Screenshot of what I saw.*
[image: Section of the previous page reappear and blink]

I wondered how it happened. I have never experienced such an incident. Initially, I thought it might be a bug on StackOverflow. To check this out I navigate to the google search engine homepage. Yes, I got the same result when the cursor hovers.

*Following is the screenshot I took.*
[image: Section of the previous page reappear on other webpages]

Then I assume this might be an issue with my chrome or worse, some error in my screen. This is not a burning question. Nevertheless, I love to know any answer to why I experience this. Perhaps my assumptions are wrong. I somebody here, who experienced same and knows the reason, Could you please be kind enough to explain it to me too?

[however when I restart the chrome I did not experience it again, sole purpose of this question is to know why something like that happened)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is probably a small bug in Chrome, triggered by very specific conditions. Check how complex the compositor can be: https://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/compositor-thread-architecture. If it persists between applications, it can be a bug in the operating system or graphics driver.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought the same. Nice explanation!

Comment: Restarting Chrome, or even a reboot, might get rid of this glitch.

Comment: Yes, @harrymc. I got rid of it. My problem was why such a thing was happening. The exact reason. I appreciate your support BTW. I post this question out of curiosity.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the screen-refresh code of Chrome. I never heard of such a bug, so it could be a side-effect of some installed extension. If you know how to recreate the problem, you could disable all extensions (same as using Incognito mode) and see. If this was a one-time only occurrence, chalk it up to the capricious computer gods.

Comment: Unfortunately, it happened accidentally. I have the habit of taking screenshots when something unusual occurs on my PC. As you have already said, I restart chrome. Then I did not see it again. As you said, yes there are many extensions I have added to chrome too. might be a side effect from it, too. Further, I am using dual monitors with different resolutions. Sometimes I get this blinking thing on chrome, I think because of mismatching resolutions. but this is the first time, something happened like this.